# Create collapsible inside of a collapsible in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to bundle this projects page into periods, like have a button for period 1 that when opened shows the buttons that I have now, and another one for period 2,3 and 4. Could anyone please show me how to do that? I'll link an image and attach the htmlcode below. Thank you very much for the help.

[image]

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #dc006a;
  color: #00365e;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #7a003b;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #DAEFF5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Pojecten</h1>
</header>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="index.html"> Home</a>
  <a href="taken.html"> Taken</a>
  <a href="smoelenboek.html"> Smoelenboek</a>
  <a href="contact.html"> Contact</a>
  <a href="ideeenbox.html">Ideeënbox</a>
  <a href="projecten.html">Projecten</a>
</div>
<section>

  <article>

    <button class="collapsible">Pc assembleren en instaleren</button>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Pc assembleren en instaleren</h1>
      <img src="IMG_9354.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
      <img src="IMG_9357.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
      <img src="IMG_9358.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Website</button>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Website</h1>
      <img src="Schermafbeelding%202021-11-03%20113631.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
      <img src="Schermafbeelding%202.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Ergotimer</button>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Ergotimer</h1>
      <img src="IMG_9189.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
      <img src="IMG_9193.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Bedrijfsvideo</button>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Bedrijfsvideo</h1>
      <img src="Afbeelding2.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
      <img src="Afbeelding3.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Documentatie</button>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Documentatie</h1>
      <img src="Afbeelding1.jpg" width="400px" height="300px">
      <img src="WhatsApp%20Image%202021-11-03%20at%2012.54.38.jpeg" width="400px" height="300px">
    </div>


  </article>
</section>

<div class="footer">
  <p></p>

</div>
```

Comment: I assume you're trying to make a step-by-step wizard of some kind? So, step 1, then step 2, and so on? But what's the problem you're facing? I've edited your question to include the image, and a runnable example of your code, but I don't see what the problem is. This isn't intended as a complaint, but instead a prompt to explain where you're stuck. Remember: we know nothing of your project except what's in this question, so you have to explain step-by-step where you're stuck. Also, consider reading the "*[ask]*" guidance. It may also be worth asking a friend to proofread your question.

Comment: Hello, I would like to make something like a menu, so I have a big button that will contain all the small buttons I already have but I can't figure out how to do that. Also the buttons are too big and don't fit the page and that results in a scrollbar at the bottom of the page. Thank you very much for your help!